# timezone JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime

Существует некая проблема.
Разрабатываю CRM систему для ведения бизнес процессов компании.
Занимаемся ремонтом техники, используем

> frontend - Backbone
>
> backend - yii2

Предполагается что данная программа в виде сайта будет сдаваться в аренду нашим партнерам по всей России. Так вот timezone везде разная по времени.
Допустим если я работаю в МСК и имею свою тайм зону - получаю в crm все заказы с определенной датой, но если я зайду в эту же CRM систему с другой точки страны то буду видеть иную дату и время.

Как быть? Как можно грамотно реализовать timezone в моем случае?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

отображать 2 времени не вариант? одно поле будет по МСК, запросом из бд с явным указанием таймзоны, другое местное.
Тут расписано о реализации: [Хабр-линк](https://habrahabr.ru/post/124297/)

Comment: спасибо! ссылка огонь